# Roo 2.0 How to change Hibernate from Create to Update with no persistence.xml

Tags: hibernate, spring-roo

I am ready to deploy my application to production and went to find the persistence.xml to change from create to update so the data is persisted....wait, no persistence.xml

How do I make that change?

Answer (score 3):

Spring Roo 2.0 generates Spring Boot applications, so you need to configure the persistence properties using the `application.properties` file. In Spring Boot applications, the `persistence.xml` file is not needed.

By default, the properties generated by the Spring Roo shell configures the persistence to persist the data and not to create it every time that the application is deployed.

This is an example about a configured persistence using an Spring Roo command:

`jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database POSTGRES --databaseName myDB --userName admin --password admin --hostName localhost`

**src/main/resources/application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:postgresql\://localhost\:5432/myDB
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

If you have configured the persistence in your project using a similar command like the provided above, you should have a really similar persistence configuration in your `application.properties` file. However, you say that your data is beeing not persisted, so you maybe could have the following problems:

1. You configure your project to use an in-memory database like HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY, so when you restart the application, the data is removed. **SOLUTION**: Change to a non-volatile database like Postgresql, Mysql, Oracle, etc. executing the `jpa` command again with the correct configuration.
2. You have execute the sample `script clinic.roo` and after that you have updated the code to generate your own application. The sample `clinic.roo` file configures an `HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY` database, so you will have the same problem as the described at the point 1. **SOLUTION**: Execute again the `jpa` command to configure the persistence with a non-volatile database.
3. You have counfigured manually the property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` in your `application.properties` file with `create` or `create-drop` value. **SOLUTION**: Change the value of this property to `validate` or `update` value.

Anyway, I recommed you that if you will work with Spring Boot applications, read more about them using the Spring Boot official documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

Also, is good to check all the available properties that you could configure in your `application.properties` file:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties

Hope it helps,

Comment: I understand what you are saying, however it doesn't quite jive with what I am seeing...for example you said, "By default, the properties generated by the Spring Roo shell configures the persistence to persist the data and not to create it every time that the application is deployed." but that is not what I am seeing it is creating as when you have "Create" instead of "update in persistence.xml.  My log.roo shows..."jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_PERSISTENT"  my application.properties has, does not have hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto

Comment: Thank you so much.This is very useful

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I asked for the time and got specifications for learning how to build a watch,

The answer is simple...

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=Update

Add this to the application.properties.

JCG did provide a hint....although he said that I changed the setting, but it wasn't there to change, and the default is "Create" not update.

The most useful was his link to

[application.properties documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties)

Thanks.